# Pandas DataFrame: test if index name is set

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with multiple columns of which one is of type datetime. Sometimes this column is used as index via **df.set_index(...)**.

On other occasions I need to reset that index in order to keep the datetime column. Now I'm looking for a way how to check if the dataframe has a default index or not. I tried this, but this is not working for all cases:

```
if df.index.name is not None:
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

I could test if the index is of type datetime, but I really wonder if there is a general method like **df.is_index_set()**. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not test the `index.name` attribute as it is not set in all scenarios. You can do the following tests :

```
In[13]:

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'))
type(df.index) == pd.RangeIndex

Out[13]: True

In[14]:    
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,3), columns=list('abc'), index=pd.date_range(dt.datetime(2017,1,1), periods=5))
df.index.is_all_dates

Out[14]: True
```

So the default index is a `pd.RangeIndex`, if your index is a `DatetimeIndex` you can just call `is_all_dates` or compare against `pd.DatetimeIndex`

The first method will handle even if you set the index to an int column which is monotonic:

```
In[27]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,3,4], 'b':35,'c':np.random.randn(5)})
df = df.set_index('a')
type(df.index) == pd.RangeIndex

Out[27]: False
```

the index `dtype` here is an `Int64Index`:

```
In[28]:
df.index

Out[28]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int64', name='a')
```